# How to run Python application on Redis on Mac?

Tags: python, redis

I have installed Redis by Mac's homebrew terminal.

I want to run this application in Github, https://github.com/ssaamm/sign-language-tutor

I don't have experience with Redis and this tutorial is a very minimal process. I have downloaded all of the required apps by pip command and ready to go. So I need help for me to type the command in terminal to run this app.

Answer (score 0):

First do `git clone "repo"` from terminal to get all the sourses
To start Redis follow this tutorial
https://redis.io/topics/quickstart
And starting the app is as stated

```
python app.py
```